# How display any type of images in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to display images in different formats?

I tried this.

```
context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
```

This will display only `jpeg` images.But I need to display images in different formats.

Comment: What have you tried so far? When you say display, do you mean in an app, for the web? in print?

Comment: Why don't you display the image using html codes?

Comment: try [this](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/9-working-with-images)

Comment: this is too general question - do you know how many different image format exist ? how many of them you like to display ? How many formats a browser can display ? do know ? what you ask is a full project, and you need to defined the requirement

Comment: @ JanR: I doing a work on asp.net with c# and sql. To retrieve images from database  I used generic handler.  How can I modify the the code I have mentioned to display  the images  like PNG and jpeg.  The code above can use only for jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Edit : 
I understand from comments that your question is :

how to set the src of an ASP.Net image to be the base64 encoded data ?
Or 
How display images that come from database in different format in an asp.net image?

Assuming that you get image bytes from database and you have an img tag

```
<img id= "img" runat= "server" />
```

You can create an extension method for byte[] like this

```
// Add a new csharp file to your project
// Add below code to it
public static class DrawingExtensions
{
    public static string ConvertToBase64ImageFormat ( this byte[] b, ImageFormats f)
    {
            // you can find other formats image mimeType and add all you need
           string mt = system.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Tiff;
           string i = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
           return string.Format("data:{0};base64,{1}",mt,i);
    }
}
public enum  ImageFormats
{
     Jpeg
     Png ,
     // And other formats
}
```

On your webform page use method like this

```
public partial class DisplayImagePage:Page
{
    public void ibDisplayImg_click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        // read image bytes from database
        Byte[] i= ReadImageFromDatabase();
        img.Src = i.ConvertToBase64ImageFormat(  ImageFormats.Png);
    }
}
```

If you want mime type for other kind of images they available with

```
 System.Web.MimeMapping
```

And use like this

```
string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName);
context.Response.ContentType = mimeType;
```

More information :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525208(v=vs.90).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping.aspx