# How to dispaly tiff images to image in ASP.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im using visual studio 2008 and i want to convert .tiff file and show it to img. I can display the image using the url get from website. But when im using the path url from server it say that the parameter is not valid. I search all in the internet but cant find a solution that could fix it. Hope you could help me. Thanks in advance.
Heres my code.

```
    string filename = "";
    file_name = "https://support.leadtools.com/SupportPortal/CS/forums/44475/PostAttachment.aspx"; (This is the link i get from website. It successfully display the image)

     // but when im using this to get the tiff it says parameter is not valid. The path i show below is just an example
    filename = "http://123.456.7.89:00/test/test.tiff";


    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(file_name);
    request.Method = "GET";
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(s);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37130469/how-display-any-type-of-images-in-asp-net/37131179#37131179

Comment: what strikes me strange is you using port 0 within your address "http://123.456.7.89:00/test/test.tiff". Or did you make a typo?

Comment: Nope its just an example. In reality it is something like this. 189.168.0.10:83/test/test.tiff

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: [ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.]
   System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream) +376654
   page_process_inc_ke1_usercontrol.convertTiff(String url) in Default.ascx.cs:28
   page_process_inc_ke1_usercontrol.set_FrmScr(String file_name) in Default.ascx.cs:88
   page_process_inc_ke1_usercontrol.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in Default.ascx.cs:112
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35

Comment: What is :00 in the end of host name? Its actually very bad. Try to replace aomething common port, for example :80

Comment: If the problem is not :00 Try to read it into a memory stream. This memory stream will be the base for bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this same kind of issue in my application once, in my case it was caused due to larger file size which wasn't properly loaded in memory at the time of accessing it. Please check the size of file you are trying to display.Hope this
helps.